# How to change default kivy logo with another image logo?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, ubuntu-16.04, buildozer

How can I change the default kivy icon logo? I tried in buildozer spec but nothing happens - when I convert my app in the apk the icon does not change.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for the icon:

> icon.filename: String, icon of your application.
>   The icon of your application. It must be a PNG of 512x512 size to be able to cover all the various platform requirements.

You must use a PNG format image.

Here is my complete spec file: [buildozer.spec](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6gtxo8bxve2g36/buildozer.spec?dl=0)

Comment: John can u show a complete code for change logo ,i trying of 10 days i feel crazy please help me thanks and sorry my english

Comment: Here is my icon line in my buildozer.spec:

`icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/resources/handandfoot.png`

And earlier in the spec file, I have:

`source.include_patterns = resources/*.png`

Comment: John now its late i cant use my computer tomorrow i send my complete buildozer spec file and step by step my action Thanks you are very gently friendly

Comment: John i have modify my buildozer spec  icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/resources/photo.png but my application not work thanks always

Comment: Is your photo.png in a director named `resources`?

Comment: if i not modify the file icon in buildozer spec  the app in my smartphone work good  normal and show my photo.jpg.Thanks Jhon for your time.

Comment: in the virtual machine buildozer in the home i have this 3 files 1) main.py 2)photo.png (the icon 512x512 ) and the 3)photo.jpg and the 4) buildozer.spec is in the places kivy. i open the terminal i write buildozer init i adjust the buildozer spec and i write buildozer android_new debug i create the file apk i transfer in my smartphone and app not work. –

Comment: in the home i have create a folder resources and i have insert the file photo.png but when i open terminal i write  buildozer android_new debug  not work i read error

Answer (score 0):

Change the `icon.filename` setting in the buildozer.spec file.

Comment: can uu do a complete example please im very confused ,i mean all step thanks so much

Comment: i have a folder with a file with image (icon.png.) a python file main.py, a file image  jpg for show  a photo and i create  a file a buildozer spec. i change(modify)  # (str) Icon of the application
    icon.filename = %(source.dir)sicon.png           i have a error